# Pythonic swap result in index error when using nested list index

Tags: python, list, swap

it's known to me that the pythonic swap can be written as :

```
a,b = b,a
list[a], list[b] = list[b], list[a]
```

but in my problem, I want to swap elements in the list, but the index I am using is the value at certain index position in the original list. It works like this:

say if I have a list nums to be swapped, and I have a index i.

```
nums = [-10,-3,-100,-1000,-239,1]  # list to swap
i = 5  # index
```

and here we can assume

```
if nums[i] > 0 and nums[i]<=len(nums)
```

What I am expecting after swap is :

```
[1, -3, -100, -1000, -239, -10]
```

the following command give me index out of range error:

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]   # gives list assignment out of range error
```

while the following command works fine:

```
t = nums[i]
nums[i] = nums[t-1]
nums[t-1] = t
```

i am confused, and please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Why are you indexing with an element of the list and not `i-1`.  I think you want `nums[i], nums[i-1] = nums[i-1], nums[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how swapping two variables works in Python.

Notice how even though you get an `AssignmentError`, if you print out your list afterwards you have

```
>>> nums
[-10, -3, -100, -1000, -239, -10]
```

This is because as the tuple created on the right hand side of

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
```

is unpacked and assigned to the left, the left hand side is evaluated during the unpacking.

So

- the RHS tuple is created with value `(-10, 1)`
- `nums[i]` is assigned to be -10
- and then you try and assign `nums[nums[i]-1]` to be `1`... but since `nums[i]` is evaluated *at this point* and is now -10, your index will now be -11, giving the error.

Comment: thanks man, that answers my question, I never knew the pythonic swapping is done with tuple.